# How to send login errors back without any redirect ? Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal, laravel-5.4

In the Laravel code: `AuthenticatesUsers.php` there's this function that returns error messages back to the user, for example if they didn't enter a registered email address:

```
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $errors = [$this->username() => trans('auth.failed')];

    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json($errors, 422);
    }

    return redirect()->back()
        ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
        ->withErrors($errors);
}
```

My issue is that I'm using a Modal box so when this function redirects to the same page the modal disappears and the user *can only* see the errors when he clicks to see the modal again.

How can I send the data back without using redirect() or any refresh ?

This is the AJAX call I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

    $('#login').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#myModal').modal();
    });

    $(document).on('submit', '#formLogin', function(e) {  
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            method: $(this).attr('method'),
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: "json"
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            console.log(data);


        })
        .fail(function(data) {
            console.log(data);

        });
    });

})

</script>
```

For completion, this is the entire Modal with both the registration and login forms:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">recharge.ae | Welcome!</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">


            <div id="reg-div">
                <h4>New customer? Register below.</h4>
                <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}" id="formRegister">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}

                            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <label for="name" class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autofocus>
                                    {{-- <small class="help-block"></small> --}}

                                    @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                        <span class="help-block">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="email-reg" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>
                                    {{-- <small class="help-block"></small> --}}

                                    @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                        <span class="help-block">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>
                                    {{-- <small class="help-block"></small> --}}

                                    @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                        <span class="help-block">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        Register and Log Me In
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div><!--#reg-div-->  


                    <div id="login-div">
                    <h4>Returning customer? Login below.</h4>
                        <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}" id="loginForm">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}

                            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>

                                    @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                        <span class="help-block">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

                                    @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                        <span class="help-block">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}> Remember Me
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        Login
                                    </button>

                                    <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                        Forgot Your Password?
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>  
                    </div><!-- #login-div -->          

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: well return a json response rather then redirecting it

Comment: like do something like `return json_encode([
            'message' => $message
        ]);`

and then in the done function do something like this `JSON.parse(data)` and from it you get the data. Append it to some variable

Comment: Is there a way to send data back with out any redirect ? @Gardezi

Comment: with this line, `return json_encode([ 'message' => $message ])` no redirect will take place but you will need to attach the errors to the html yourself

Answer (score 1):

Well, return a JSON response rather than redirecting the page. Here's how to do it. Rather than this

```
return redirect()->back()
        ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
        ->withErrors($errors);
```

write this

```
return json_encode([ 'errorr' => $$errors ]);
```

and via above line, you get the data in the done function of the ajax. There you just need to  parse that JSON like this

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
```

and then you can access the errors like this `data.errors` **but here you need to keep one thing in mind you will need to attach these errors  in the html yourself**

**P.S** If there is anything that you don't understand feel free to ask

Comment: Thank you. I basically replaced the redirect line with this line: return json_encode([ '$errors' => $errors, '$request' =>  $request->only($this->username(), 'remember')]); and I receive this error in the debugger:  Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::sendFailedLoginResponse() must be an instance of App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request, instance of Illuminate\Http\Request given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\onlinerecharge\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php on line 50

Comment: what is line number 50 ?

Comment: and why are you doing this `'$request' => $request->only($this->username()` most probably the error is in this line `'$request' => $request->only($this->username()`

Comment: This is 50:        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);

Comment: oh I get it my bad

Comment: Your this function `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::sendFailedLoginRe‌sponse()` is expecting an instance of this class `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request` but you are passing it the instance of this class `Illuminate\Http\Request`. Please read the error it's self explanatory

Comment: @Seio check what kind of object this function `sendFailedLoginRe‌‌sponse()` is receiving

Comment: @Seio If you are still facing some error feel free to ask

Comment: Thank you. Last think I tried is replace the namespace of request like this: public function login(\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request $request) which is the function line 50 belongs to. and I receive this error:Class App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request does not exist.

Comment: This change is in AuthenticatesUsers.php @Gardezi

Comment: @Seio Well then that means that this file is not present on the path that you are telling. Try running `composer dumpautoload` and see if it works